# How to return the range of values shared between two data frames in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, range, tidyr

I have several data frames that have the same columns names, and `ID`
, the following to are the start `from` and end `to` of a range and `group` label from each of them.

What I want is to find which values of`from` and `to` from one of the `data frames` are included in the range of the other one. I leave an example picture to ilustrate what I want to achieve (no graph is need for the moment)

[image: I want to obtain the range shared between two data frames]

I thought I could accomplish this using `between()` of the `dplyr package` but no. This could be accomplish using if `between()` returns true then return the maximum value of `from` and the minimum value of `to` between the data frames.

I leave example data frames and the `results` I'm willing to obtain.

```
a <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),from=c(1,500,1000,1,500,1000,1,500,1000),
                to=c(400,900,1400,400,900,1400,400,900,1400),group=rep("a",9))
b <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),from=c(300,1200,1900,1400,2800,3700,1300,2500,3500),
                to=c(500,1500,2000,2500,3000,3900,1400,2800,3900),group=rep("b",9))
results <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,3),from=c(300,500,1200,1400,1300),
                      to=c(400,500,1400,1400,1400),group=rep("a, b",5))
```

I tried using this function which will return me the values when there is a match but it doesn't return me the range shared between them

```
f <- function(vec, id) {
  if(length(.x <- which(vec >= a$from & vec <= a$to & id == a$ID))) .x else NA
}
b$fromA <- a$from[mapply(f, b$from, b$ID)]
b$toA <- a$to[mapply(f, b$to, b$ID)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can play with the idea that the starting and ending points are in different columns and the ranges for the same group (a and b) do not overlap. This is my solution. I have called 'point_1' and 'point_2' your mutated 'from' and 'to' for clarity.

You can bind the two dataframes and compare the `from` col with the previous value `lag(from)` to see if the actual value is smaller. Also you compare the previous `lag(to)` to the actual `to` col to see if the max value of the range overlap the previous range or not.

Important, these operations do not distinguish if the two rows they are comparing are from the same group (a or b). Therefore, filtering the NAs in `point_1` (the new mutated 'from' column) you will remove wrong mutated values.
Also, note that I assume that, for example, a range in 'a' cannot overlap two rows in 'b'. In your 'results' table that doesn't happen but you should check that in your dataframes.

```
res = rbind(a,b) %>%  # Bind by rows
  arrange(ID,from) %>% # arrange by ID and starting point (from)
  group_by(ID) %>% # perform the following operations grouped by IDs
# Here is the trick. If the ranges for the same ID and group (i.e. 1,a) do   
# not overlap, when you mutate the following cols the result will be NA for 
# point_1.
  mutate(point_1 = ifelse(from <= lag(to), from, NA),
         point_2 = ifelse(lag(to)>=to, to, lag(to)),
         groups = paste(lag(group), group, sep = ',')) %>% 
  filter(! is.na(point_1)) %>%  # remove NAs in from
  select(ID,point_1, point_2, groups)  # get the result dataframe
```

If you play a bit with the code, not using the `filter()` and `select()` you will see how that's work.

```
> res
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID point_1 point_2 groups
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> 
1     1     300     400 a,b   
2     1     500     500 b,a   
3     1    1200    1400 a,b   
4     2    1400    1400 a,b   
5     3    1300    1400 a,b
```

Comment: That made the trick. Really usefull your answer!